# cant save user uploads in object storage

Tags: gitlab, devops, gitlab-omnibus, netapp, ontap

hi guys I just set up a gitlab instance in multi node architecture.
I also configured an s3 compatible storage using NetApp onTap s3.

this is my configuration for the object storage:

```
    gitlab_rails['object_store']['enable'] = true
    gitlab_rails['object_store']['connection'] = {
       'provider' => 'AWS',
       'endpoint' => 'https://mys3instance.example',
       'aws_access_key_id' => 'someaccesskeyid',
       'aws_secret_access_key' => 'someaccesskey',
       'aws_signature_version' => 4,
       'path_style' => true,
       'enable_signature_v4_streaming' => false
}

    gitlab_rails['object_store']['objects']['artifacts']['bucket'] = 'gitlab/artifacts'
    gitlab_rails['object_store']['objects']['external_diffs']['bucket'] = 'gitlab/external-diffs'
    gitlab_rails['object_store']['objects']['lfs']['bucket'] = 'gitlab/lfs'
    gitlab_rails['object_store']['objects']['uploads']['bucket'] = 'gitlab/uploads'
    gitlab_rails['object_store']['objects']['packages']['bucket'] = 'gitlab/packages'
    gitlab_rails['object_store']['objects']['dependency_proxy']['bucket'] = 'gitlab/dependency-proxy'
    gitlab_rails['object_store']['objects']['terraform_state']['bucket'] = 'gitlab/terraform-state'
```

then I tried uploading any attachment(favicon for example) and gitlab by default stores the attachment on my local storage instead of the s3 bucket.
also when trying to migrate the attachment from local storage to my s3 bucket
i catch the following error from the sidekiq logs:
"object storage is not enabled for FaviconUploader"

I have 2 questions:
first, can I somehow make gitlab save the objects I gave him in the configuration file on the s3 bucket by default?
and second, what can cause the error im seeing?

tried looking for any additional configurations for the connection setup in the gitlab.rb file, and also checked permissions on the s3 bucket and everything seems fine.
i have full access to the bucket to write and save stuff.